# Email Markup does not show the button in the subject line on G Suite (it’s working in Gmail)

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, google-schemas

I did Email Markup tests in Gmail with positive results, but in G Suite Gmail (company) the same script does not show the button in the subject line.

I do not know if it is related, but before setting up Dkim registration in G Suite, we recieve external emails with Email Markup, will any additional permission, or additional code, be needed?

I used the example code of the following link:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/apps-script-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

The Quickstart code worked for me. Make sure your email address is [signed](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/registering-with-google) by Google, as it is required to use Schemas.